# Add style to part of a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, split, classname

I want to bold my text between `*`. For example:
This text is ***bold*** and this two ***bold bold***.
I can also use a mark that is not bold.

I map my string in as a value. (I want to also find all Enters so I split them by '\n')

```
value.split('\n').map((el, index) => (
        <div key={`${el} ${index}`}>
          {el.split('*').map((word, index) => (
            <div key={`${word} ${index}`} className={classNames(classes.word, index % 2 !== 0 && classes.bold)}>{word}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
    )
```